# Ubuntu, Firefox, and other things Freeze and/or Crash!

Tags: nvidia, firefox, lenovo, freeze, browser

I  have a Lenovo P50 laptop with the following specs:

CPU:     i7
Ram:     32GB
Video:   NVIDIA Quadro M1000M
SSD0: 1TB
SSD1: 512MB
SSD2: 512MB

I have tried the following Ubuntu versions:

<strike>14.04.6-desktop-amd64</strike>
18.04.5-''
20.04.1-''

I have closely followed the instructions found on the Lenovo site found [here](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/thinkpad_p43s_p53s_ubuntu_installation_whitepaper_v1.0.pdf)

My problem is the same on every installation.  When I launch Firefox or Opera, they both freeze and or crash.  Sometimes, I can get Firefox to work for a little while and Opera usually works for about 5-10 minutes before crashing.  I am entirely new to Linux and I don't have the slightest clue on where to begin.  I have a hunch that I'm having a problem with the NVIDIA but I don't really know.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  I am not using any add-ons and I have turned off hardware acceleration.

Edit:  I updated the BIOS but still experience the issue.

Edit: ###### **UBUNTU IS NOW FREEZING RANDOMLY TOO** ######

Comment: Have you done any driver or hardware enablement actions on the machine, yet? If not, open a terminal and run this: `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. This may resolve your graphics issues while also enabling some of your other devices to work better 

Comment: Thanks, will do.  I will re-install 20.04 and get back to you.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/   *I realize the other releases are on-topic, but why not have tried 16.04 or something supported & thus on-topic for this site*

Comment: `opera` is not default on any official installation, thus what `firefox` are you using?  have you tried *snaps* if so which?  what package version(s) did you try? given the `opera` also implies you're not just using default browsers.

Comment: Thanks Matigo, when I run that command, the result is "linux-generic-hwe-20.04 is already the newest version..."

Comment: The firefox version is 79.0 and I only installed Opera because firefox wasn't working and to show that it doesn't seem to be an issue related to firefox.

Comment: Open System Monitor - Resources tab, and watch to see what might be tanking.

Comment: Thanks, user3169.  Unfortunately nothing notable in System Monitor when Firefox freezes.  All 8 cpus are at 10% and memory is at around 8%.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like RAM issue. Check it by memtest86

Comment: Thanks.  I searched how to use memtest and I found that the process for brining up the grub menu are (1) reboot and (2) hold the shift key.  It doesn't work.  I can't get the grub menu to appear.

Comment: Ok, I managed to make a bootable USB for memtest and it ran with no errors.  Do you have anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you run quick test or full? I think it's hardware issue. You can test browsers with disabled hardware acceleration https://www.itechtics.com/disable-hardware-acceleration-in-google-chrome-firefox-opera-and-vivaldi/

Comment: Yes, I have tried disabling hardware acceleration and made certain no add-ins are installed

Comment: As far as the Ram test, when memtest booted, it started on its own and was anything but quick.  So I don't know if it was the "quick test" or not.  I can't get memtest86 to show up in Grub so I downloaded the most current version 9. When it started, it's image wouldn't display properly, so I then used version 4.  I'm not sure how UEFI works over legacy BIOS but my system is supposed to be capable.

Comment: I let memtest run for another 5 hours and not a single error.  One thing to note, my SO-DIMM slots are not equal.  There are four slots available and only three are used.  Two have matching 8GB sticks and the other has a 16GB stick.  I'm not sure on the speeds.  However, if there was truly a problem with memory, why would Ubuntu keep going and Firefox freeze?

Comment: Now the OS is also randomly freezing.  I think you're right, there is a hardware problem but I'm not sure it's memory.

Comment: It looks like it's some kind of CPU problem.  When I turn off mutli-processing in BIOS, it works fine, but everything is obviously slower.  Is there some way I can control the i7 core processor???

Comment: You can install gnome shell extentions like https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/ to monitor temperatures and https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/ to manage CPU perfomance

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  When I disable Core Multi-Processing in BIOS, everything seems to work great.  However, even with Intel (R) Hyper-Threading Technology enabled, I only have two cores.  It's a four core processor and with hyper-threading, I could have eight, which would be optimal for me.